# Get todays appointments from outlook with powershell: Unwanted results

Tags: powershell, outlook

I'm extracting todays appointments with the following code:

```
$olFolderCalendar = 9
$ol = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$ns = $ol.GetNamespace('MAPI')
$Start = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToShortDateString() + " 00:00"
$End = (Get-Date).AddDays(+1).ToShortDateString() + " 00:00"

$Filter = "[MessageClass]='IPM.Appointment' AND [Start] > '$Start' AND [End] < '$End'"

$Appointments = $ns.GetDefaultFolder($olFolderCalendar).Items
$Appointments.Sort("[Start]")
$Appointments.IncludeRecurrences = $false

foreach ($Appointment in $Appointments.Restrict($Filter) ) {
    ...
}
```

All todays appointments are listed but also a lot of recurring appointments that are NOT taking place today (birthdays, weekly appointments, ...). Any idea how to avoid that?

EDIT: Seems like all this unwanted appointments are originally from my mobile synced to outlook. I'll try the script on a 'clean' PC.

EDIT: I tried the script on another PC without synced elements and it's the same: All recurring elements are display whether they are today or not.
    AND [IsRecurring] = '$False'
is not helping either.

Answer (score 5):

"The issue is that this calendar has been around for 15 years, so this takes an extremely long time to run" - me too

in addition to the "restrict" method, there is a "find" method, which seems to only get the first result, so you then have to loop through with a 'findnext' method to find the rest. i found that initially splitting non-recurring appointments from recurring appointments with two separate "restrict" filters, and then using a "find" filter on my 2.14 million recurring appointments was WAY faster than piping them to a where-object.

```
$outlook=New-Object -com outlook.application
$mapi=$outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

$Start = ((Get-Date).adddays(-1).ToShortDateString())
$end = ((Get-Date).AddDays(7)).ToShortDateString()

$Filter = "[MessageClass]='IPM.Appointment' AND [Start] > '$Start'  AND [Start] < '$end' AND [isrecurring] = 'False'"

$Appointments = ($mapi.GetDefaultFolder(9).Items).restrict($filter)
$Appointments.Sort("[Start]")


$recurringFilter = "[MessageClass]='IPM.Appointment' AND [isrecurring] = 'True'" #leave the date filter out

$recurringappointments = ($mapi.GetDefaultFolder(9).Items).restrict($recurringfilter)
$RecurringAppointments.Sort("[Start]")
$recurringappointments.includerecurrences = $true


$array = @()

foreach($appointment in $Appointments)
    {
    $array +=$Appointment
    } 


$recurringappointment = $recurringappointments.find("  [Start] >= '$start' AND  [Start] <= '$end'") #use the date filter here
$array += $recurringappointment
    do
        {
        $recurringappointment = $recurringappointments.FindNext()
        $array += $recurringappointment
        }
    until(!$recurringappointment)
  
$array | select subject, start, isrecurring | sort start
```

Comment: Reduced the runtime for me from around 20-30 minutes to around 4 seconds. Why does it have `[Start] > '$Start'  AND [Start] < '$end'` and then `[Start] >= '$start' AND  [Start] <= '$end'` later? Is that correct? For my script I used `[Start] >= '$Start'  AND [Start] < '$end'` for both.

Answer (score 4):

The initial query must include the original appointment of the series, so if the series started 3 months ago, the collection of appointments ($folder.items) date range must be set accordingly.

Afterwards you can filter for the desired date range.

This code works:

```
Function Get-OutlookCalendar
{
 echo starting...
 Add-type -assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook" | out-null
 $olFolders = "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders" -as [type]
 $outlook = new-object -comobject outlook.application
 $namespace = $outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
 $folder = $namespace.getDefaultFolder($olFolders::olFolderCalendar)

 $a = Get-Date -Hour 0 -Minute 00 -Second 00
 $b = (Get-Date -Hour 0 -Minute 00 -Second 00).AddDays(7)
 echo From $a To $b

 $Appointments = $folder.Items
 $Appointments.IncludeRecurrences = $true
 $Appointments.Sort("[Start]")

 $Appointments | Where-object { $_.start -gt $a -AND $_.start -lt $b } | Select-Object -Property IsRecurring, RecurrenceState, Subject, Start, Location

} #end function Get-OutlookCalendar
```

To run this -for dummies, like myself yesterday :)

```
cmd
powershell
PS C:\Users\Jose\Documents\WindowsPowerShell> Import-Module -Name Outlook\expcal.psm1 -Force
PS C:\Users\Jose\Documents\WindowsPowerShell> Get-OutlookCalendar
```

Comment: I think this answer works for me. The issue is that this calendar has been around for 15 years, so this takes an extremely long time to run.

Comment: Thanks, glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your filter:

```
$Filter = "[MessageClass]='IPM.Appointment' AND [Start] > '$Start' AND [End] < '$End'  AND     [IsRecurring] = '$False'"
```

Worked for me here.

Comment: That is not working for me but it would also have the effect, that recurring appointments that take place today won't be displayed. But that ones I want to have as well.

Answer (score 1):

If @marceljg suggestion doesn't work for you then consider filtering out undesired appointments by piping to the `Where-Object` cmdlet

Comment: Thanks for this hint but I can't filter them for the same reason @marceljg suggestions isn't working. I want to display the recurring events (on the specific date e.g. today) but not all them every day.

Answer (score 1):

Realizing this is an extremely delayed answer, but it's in your filter. By using `>` and `<` you are excluding items that start or end at midnight, which covers all-day items and your repeating items.

Try the following:

```
$filter = "[MessageClass]='IPM.Appointment' AND [Start] >= '$Start' AND [End] <= '$End'"
```

Also put the `IncludeRecurrences` line *before* the `Sort`:

```
$Appointments.IncludeRecurrences = $true
$Appointments.Sort("[Start]")
```