# Send email only when there is an appointment (Outlook)

Tags: vba, outlook

Hi I am new to VBA here.
I have edited a code accordingly from :
https://www.slipstick.com/developer/code-samples/running-outlook-macros-schedule/

Currently, this code will email tomorrow's agenda (extracted from a shared calendar) , whether there is any appointment or not. I would like to only send the email when there is an appointment. May I know if it is possible to do so? Many thanks for your time!

### --
Does anyone know if it is possible to use the filter / restrict function to only export the calendar when there is appointmentitems? or how should i create an if.. then condition to exit the sub if there is no appointment schedule for the day?

It worked with the.Restrict filter!

```
Public Sub SendPrettyAgenda()
Dim oNamespace As NameSpace
Dim oFolder As Folder
Dim oCalendarSharing As CalendarSharing
Dim objMail As MailItem
Dim wd As Integer

Dim oAppointmentItem As Object


Set oNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

Set objOwner = oNamespace.CreateRecipient("xxx@email.com")
    objOwner.Resolve
       
If objOwner.Resolved Then
   'MsgBox objOwner.Name
      

Set oFolder = oNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(objOwner, olFolderCalendar)

End If



Set oCalendarSharing = oFolder.GetCalendarExporter

' get the day - send sat/sun/monday out Fri night
' Sun = 1, Mon = 2, Tue = 3, Wed = 4, Thu = 5, Fri = 6, Sat = 7
' none set Sat/Sun
wd = Weekday(Date)
If wd >= 1 And wd <= 7 Then
    lDays = Date + 1
End If



With oCalendarSharing
' options are olFreeBusyAndSubject, olFullDetails, olFreeBusyOnly
    .CalendarDetail = olFullDetails
    .IncludeWholeCalendar = False
    .IncludeAttachments = False
    .IncludePrivateDetails = True
    .RestrictToWorkingHours = False
    .StartDate = Date + 1
    .EndDate = lDays

    
End With


' prepare as email
' options: olCalendarMailFormatEventList, olCalendarMailFormatDailySchedule

Set objMail = oCalendarSharing.ForwardAsICal(olCalendarMailFormatDailySchedule)


 ' Send the mail item to the specified recipient.
 With objMail
 .Recipients.Add "xxx@email.com"
 

 .Subject = "Tomorrow 's Schedule | " & (Format(Date + 1, "dddd, dd-mmm-yyyy"))
' Remove the attached ics
 .Attachments.Remove (1)


 .Send 'for testing, change to .send


 End With

bobo:
Set oCalendarSharing = Nothing
Set oFolder = Nothing
Set oNamespace = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get only today's appointments through Outlook VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62923113/get-only-todays-appointments-through-outlook-vba)

Comment: Hi, does anyone know if it is possible to use the filter / restrict function to only export the calendar when there is appointmentitems? or how should i create an if.. then condition to exit the sub if there is no appointment schedule for the day?