# olFolderCalendar in Outlook Interop assembly not showing all calendar entries

Tags: powershell, outlook

I am using a function (`Get-OutlookCalendar`) from the [Microsoft Scripting Guys blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-export-outlook-calendar-information/) that looks like this:

```
 Add-type -assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook" | out-null
 $olFolders = "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders" -as [type]
 $outlook = new-object -comobject outlook.application
 $namespace = $outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
 $folder = $namespace.getDefaultFolder($olFolders::olFolderCalendar)
 $folder.items |
 Select-Object -Property Subject, Start, Duration, Location
```

It works great.  The problem is that it doesn't seem to return all my calendar entries.  For example, I call the function with a where clause like this:

```
$datefmt = "MM/dd/yyyy"
$today = (Get-Date).ToString($datefmt)
$tomorrow = ((Get-Date).AddDays(1)).ToString($datefmt)
Get-OutlookCalendar | where-object { $_.start -gt [datetime]$today -and $_.start -lt [datetime]$tomorrow } | Select-Object -Property Subject,Start |Sort-Object Start
```

From Outlook, I see four entries but the code only returns one entry.

Is the calendar displayed in the UI somehow aggregating multiple folders or can anyone suggest some other reason?

Comment: Replace all curly (ugly) so-called 'smart-quote' thingies into straight ones. You should never use them in code.

Comment: @Theo - thanks, I didn't notice that.  It came directly from the site that way, PS doesn't seem to care either way.  I did update them but it didn't change the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that what I missing was to set the `Recurrences` property.  I ran into this later in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9892352/get-todays-appointments-from-outlook-with-powershell-unwanted-results) by @Jose-Manuel-Gomez-Alvarez.  It seemed on the right track but wasn't working for me.  I found this [Microsoft Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.includerecurrences) which described a particular order that was required.  This is doing what I want, showing everything on my calendar for the period:

```
 Add-type -assembly “Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook” | out-null
 $olFolders = “Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders” -as [type]
 $outlook = new-object -comobject outlook.application
 $namespace = $outlook.GetNameSpace(“MAPI”)
 $folder = $namespace.getDefaultFolder($olFolders::olFolderCalendar)
 $appts = $folder.items               # Per referenced article
 $appts.Sort("[Start]")               # the sequence of these
 $appts.IncludeRecurrences = $true    # is very important

 $start = (Get-Date)
 $end = $start.AddDays(1)
 $filter = "[Start] >= `"$($start.toString('g'))`" and [End] <= `"$($end.toString('g'))`" "
 $someitems = $appts.restrict($filter)
 $someitems | Select-Object -Property Subject, Start, End, Duration, Location
```

Answer (score 1):

Because of the function's examples, you are formatting a DateTime object to string and then later you convert that back to a DateTime object to fit parameter `start`.

There's no need for that and you can simply do

```
$today    = (Get-Date).Date      # .Date sets the time to midnight (00:00:00)
$tomorrow = $today.AddDays(1)

Get-OutlookCalendar | 
  Where-Object { $_.Start -gt $today -and $_.Start -lt $tomorrow } | 
  Select-Object -Property Subject,Start | Sort-Object Start
```

Now, the function will try and find calendar items between (at the time of writing this) Monday, August 24 2020 00:00:00 and Tuesday, August 25 2020 00:00:00, in other words all calendar items that start today.

Comment: Thank you, @Theo!  That's much cleaner and thanks for pointing out the conversions to string/date.  I made the updates to my local script.  For some reason it still doesn't pull all the calendar entries that I see on the UI.  For example, right now I see four meetings on my calendar, two tentative and two accepted but the script only pulls one meeting.